# Clean way of instantiating and updating JavaScript objects? (Is my approach valid?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, javascript-framework, instantiation

I'd like a clean way of instantiating and updating JavaScript objects.
Right now I'm using this approach:

```
myApp.chart.GridController = Backbone.Base.extend({

    _defaults : {

        width : 500,
        height : 500,
        indicatorXMin : 100,
        indicatorXMax : 10000, 
        indicatorXScale : "log",

        xScale : undefined,
        yScale : undefined,

        xAxis : undefined,
        yAxis : undefined,

        element : undefined,

    },

    options : {},

    constructor: function (options) {
        this.options = $.extend(this.options.defaults, options);
        this.render();
    },

    update : function(options) {
        this.options = $.extend(this.options, options);
        this.render();
    },

    render : function(){
        this.updateAxes();
        this.draw();
    }

[...]
```

1. Is there a better approach to setting and overriding default values?
2. When using this approach, I always have to use the "options" prefix for all my variables, is there a cleaner workaround?
3. In the above example, _defaults.xAxis and _defaults.yAxis are actually derived from the other variables. Should these go inside the _defaults object anyway or where do I place them? (I'd prefer not to have to keep track of which variables are "derived options" and not ...)

---

3) EDIT:
I mean the object attributes that are not supposed to be overridden in the constructor but instead be updated based on the other attributes.

Not using $.extend I do something like:

var a,b;
var c;

constructor(a,b)
this.a = a;
this.b = b;

this.c = a+b;

I'm just wondering if it's problematic to put c among the defaults ...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand (3) above - maybe if you add an example of what you think you might do instead of the code you posted above.

Comment: @Pointy: I added a brief example. Thx :=)

Comment: Ah OK I see now - I'll add to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That approach is going to have a problem because "$.extend()" **overwrites** the contents of the first argument.  For the "defaults", that'll be bad :-)

```
    this.options = $.extend({}, this._defaults, options);
```

That's the normal way to avoid the problem: pass in a brand new empty object as the first argument, and then that'll be populated first with all the default values and then with whatever was passed in to override those.

There's not really a good way to "get around" having to refer to variables via the "options" handle.  You *can* make local copies, and while that's harmless in a local sense it can introduce bugs.

*edit* — OK now that I see what you mean about (3), I think that what I would do is compute those properties *after* you've extended the defaults.  That way, even if client code passes in something that really shouldn't be there, you'll just overwrite that with the legitimate values.

So, something like:

```
    this.options = $.extend({}, this._defaults, options);
    this.options.something = someFunction();
    this.options.somethingElse = whatever();
```